# Bounding the Hausdorff measure of the image of a map

Tags: integration, hausdorff-measure

Let $\phi:[0,1]^n\to [0,1]^m$ be continuous everywhere and smooth almost everywhere.

The Hausdorff measure of $\phi([0,1]^n)$ is given by
$$\mathcal{H}^n\left(\phi\left([0,1]^n\right)\right)=\int_{[0,1]^n}\sqrt{\det\left(\nabla \phi^T\cdot\nabla \phi\right)}$$

I am wondering if possible to say that

$$\mathcal{H}^n\left(\phi\left([0,1]^n\right)\right)~\le~C\left[\int_{[0,1]^n}\left|\nabla\phi\right|\right]^n$$
for some $C>0$. I have done a lot of test cases and the result seems true but I am having trouble proving this.

Comment: did you mean to give a definition to lowercase $d$?

Comment: Sorry I meant to use n instead of d